# Is it not correct to do api call without useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I want to do an api call after a button is clicked in react.But I have read that to do async tasks, we use useEffect.
So is it okay to not use useEffect and do an api call without it?
I think that without using useEffect an api call would block the render.
useEffect runs depending on deps Array.
It is used to do async tasks.
But I want to do a api call onClick.So its not possible to use useEffect.
So,What is the correct way to do an api call if it has to be done on Click?

Comment: "*I think that without using `useEffect` an api call would block the render.*" - no, an *async* api call just doesn't work in the render method. The problem with calling it directly, i.e. without `useEffect`, is that it would fire the call on every render run, and even recursively when it sets state with the result.

Comment: "*But I want to do a api call `onClick`*" - sure, that's totally fine. It is not called from the render code. You don't need an effect hook here.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination Bergi!
I understood it.
More clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do api call with and w/o the `useEffect`, both are fine.

And no, you won't block the api call if you don't use `useEffect`.

```
const App =  () => {
  
  const makeApiCall = async () => {
    // the execution of this function stops
    // at this await call, but rest of the App component
    // is still executes
    const res = await fetch("../");

  }

  ...
};
```

Comment: Totally Agreed.But then they say You are not following the "React way".Because doing api call should not be part of React,right?here they recommend to  use useEffect.
Thats where I am confused.

Comment: `useEffect` is for sideEffects indeed. But that doesn't mean you can call apis like this.
This function is not invoked itself. So even in multiple renders it is not causing any side effect.

Comment: Ok. got it. 
Thanks Shravan for helping me out!

Comment: I did try that. But I dont have `reputation` .So it doesnt allow me to upvote.

Comment: No worries @Prajwal. Happy to help mate :)